# How to set new turtles direction from average of 2 angles in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I need help on how write this formula using Netlogo. (Refer to figure per attached)
I'm trying set new heading for the agent by calculate the average of 2 angles between leader's heading and agent's heading. New heading for the agent should be change to 27. Below is the code that i use, but it does not work the way I want:

[image]

```
to change-heading
  let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ]
  if any?  nearby-leaders in-radius vision
  [turn-towards average-heading-towards-leaders max-cohere-turn ]
end

to-report average-heading-towards-leaders  
 let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ]
 report average-heading ([heading] of one-of nearby-leaders ) heading
end

to-report average-heading [a b]
 report (a - (subtract-headings a b) / 2) mod 360
end
```

Really need advice on this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sidesteps the trig but this works

```
to-report average-heading[a b]
Let h (a - (subtract-headings a b) / 2) mod 360
Let s (a + b) / 2
Ifelse h < s [report h][report s]
]
end
```

In your code

```
to-report average-heading-towards-leaders 
report average-heading ([heading] of one-of nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ] ) heading
end
```

Mark II

Comment: but then how to define the a and b value?

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are the two headings you want averaged. I could have called them heading-one and heading-two.

Comment: I tried to used the "average-headings [a b] like u mention above, however it pop-up error message "average-heading-towards-leaders expected 2 inputs" when i ask any turtle near to leader **set heading towards average-heading-towards-leaders**

Comment: I don't see the procedure average-heading in what you wrote. I will amend my answer to clarify usage.

Comment: I just changed my code according to your opinion(refer code above), but when I check, turtles heading not the average angle between the leader's heading and turtle's heading. Is there other ways more accurate to examine the turtles heading instead of inspect the turtles?

Comment: You could use the key word SHOW or ask the turtles [set label heading]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63818/discussion-between-juliana-and-king-ink).